# Google Sheet: Combining days into weeks in query

Tags: google-sheets, calendar, pivot, report, spreadsheet

I'm preparing a small data spreadsheet in Google Sheet, where by using pivot table with query I already managed to receive table as follows:

|  | Day 1 | Day 3 | Day 8 | Day 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Article 1 | Volume sold day 1 | Volume sold day 3 | Volume sold day 8 | Volume sold day 12 |
| Article 2 | Volume sold day 1 | Volume sold da3 | Volume sold day 8 | Volume sold day 12 |

Basically we're speaking about the table summing up sales with volumes sold each day (what's important, is that days are random).

I'm trying to sum up the volumes of each day to a whole calendar week so the outcome, I'm thinking of, is:

|  | Week 1 | Week 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Article 1 | Volume sold days 1 + 3 | Volume sold days 8 + 12 |
| Article 2 | Volume sold days 1 + 3 | Volume sold days 8 + 12 |

I'm filtering bigger table using query but this is not that important. To make it short I wrote following code:

```
=QUERY(<range>; 
"select <article_column>,
sum(<volume_column>)
group by <article_column>
pivot <days_column>")
```

The question is: is there a way to combine week days from separate columns into a whole week and sum up the volumes sold within this particular week? Internet gives me a hint about using ARRAYFORMULA, but since my source database is kind of big, I'm trying to keep all the formulas as simple as it's possible.

Would you be able to recommend good resource to learn more about it? For last 2 hours I keep running in circles over the internet and I cannot find a good idea how to solve it.

Thanks in advance for your hints!

Comment: so the final output you want is `Volume sold days 1 + 3` or `Volume sold days 4` ? share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IOMU4qrAAz_VYQrZZLZ0SSVDkT2z00o_LOvsfVlb9V0

Of course I did desired output manually since I don't know how to automatize it. Instead of "Week 1" in the header can be just a first calendar day of this week - this would be already enough

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({"Week "&WEEKNUM(A2:A100)\ B2:C100}; 
 "select Col2,sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! Thank you VERY MUCH for that, you saved my day! :)

I tried to extrapolate the dates reaching even until end of the year, and it seems that the spreadsheet mixes the order of the weeks. I did that in the file I shared so would you be so kind and take a look at this, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BartoszK try: `=INDEX(QUERY({"Week "&TEXT(WEEKNUM(A2:A2100); "00")\ B2:C2100}; 
 "select Col2,sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"))`

Comment: Great, thanks! I needed to change one thing, since spreadsheet started counting from Week 2 with your solution, so I changed the formula into:

=INDEX(QUERY({"Week "&TEXT((WEEKNUM(A2:A2100)-1); "00")\ B2:C2100}; 
 "select Col2,sum(Col3) group by Col2 pivot Col1"))